# How can I implement an interface that can take many object types

Tags: c#

excuse what seems like a real noobie question but how can I implement the following

```
public interface IViewModel    {
        void Map<T>();
    }


  public class CarViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        public string Color { get; private set; }
        public int Tyres { get; private set; }

public CarViewModel(Car _car)

    }
```

//this is where the problem is  - there can be many differnt kind of object but I want them all to implement a Map function. I want to be able to assign the properties to incoming object. I also need to cater for IList of cars coming in that need to be populated. I suspect I am not using Generics properly

```
public void Map<T>(Car _car){
Color = _car.Color;
Tyres = _car.Tyres;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
public interface IViewModel<T>
{
    void Map(T domainObject);
}

public class CarViewModel : IViewModel<Car>
{
    public Map(Car domainObject) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I suspect I am not using Generics properly

and you are correct.  Additionally, you are not using [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism) properly.

If you want to polymorphically accept several different types that all have something in common, then you need to create an interface that is the parent type of all of the types you will be using.  You can do this without using any Generics at all.

What Generics (aka parametric polymorphism) gives you is a way to create *one* type that is *parameterized* by another type (and thus behaves like many different types).  For example, `IList<T>` is parameterized by a type variable `T` -- then `IList<string>` and `IList<int>` are two separate types (with many possible subtypes each), but you only have to write the code once.

What are your actual requirements for this design?  What are your `ViewModel` classes trying to accomplish?

Comment: hi,

I have a domain object (Car for example) and I am trying to package it up into another object called 'CarViewModel' I am using ASP.NET MVC and the viewmodel is what is to be retrieved by the Controller

this is fairly straight forward but I have many differnt kind of ViewModel objects and I want them all to do the same on their respective domain object.

Comment: so I want a common function in all the viewmodel objects called 'Map' for example that will perform it own 'packaging' of the ViewModel object from the service/domain object(s)

Comment: What if you make all your domain (model) objects inherit from an interface `IMyObject` and then build an abstract class `AbstractViewModel<T> where T : IMyObject`.  Fill in your common bits of functionality there.  Then make `CarViewModel` a subclass of `AbstractViewModel<Car>` and override functionality as necessary.  Would that work for you?